# Set a variable from a function node.js

Tags: node.js

​I am very new to nodejs. I have been playing around trying to implement a npm package node-cmd, execute the cmd and set the output equal to a variable. I have implemented the following:

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');
var dir;
function test(data)
        {
         console.log("data content: " + data)
        };
var outputStuff = cmd.get('pwd',test);
console.log("outputStuff content: " + outputStuff);
```

output:

```
outputStuff content: undefined'
data content: /Users/jduff/Development/node/systemProperties
```

It is clear that the var "outputStuff" is set prior to executing the cmd.get function and returns 'undefined'. So my recollection from the course I took a while ago is that the outputStuff variable is being hoisted and set prior to executing the function. My question is how would I get the contents of the function to be set to the variable outputStuff.

```
console.log(outputStuff)
```

output:

```
outputStuff content: /Users/jduff/Development/node/systemProperties
```

Any insights to what I am missing will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: `node-cmd` is running async and calling the `test` callback upon completion of the `pwd` call. Since it's async, `outputStuff` isn't set.